# Ingress config causes All backend services are in UNHEALTHY state

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, janusgraph

I'm setting up a Janusgraph instance with Kubernetes on GKE and my internal load balancer works fine. However, when using Ingress to expose an https endpoint, I can't resolve the following status:

```
All backend services are in UNHEALTHY state
```

My Service configuration is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-04-24T05:53:47Z"
  labels:
    app: janusgraph
    chart: janusgraph-0.2.1
    heritage: Tiller
    release: janusgraph
  name: janusgraph-service
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "476142"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/janusgraph-service
  uid: f6c80efa-85ef-11ea-983b-42010a960015
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.43.250.31
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31038
    port: 8182
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8182
  selector:
    app: janusgraph
    release: janusgraph
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.236.228.15
```

My Ingress configuration is:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: '{"k8s-be-31038--126ca7f10f7eb9fb":"Unknown"}'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: k8s-fw-default-dispatchdqs--126ca7f10f7eb9fb
    ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: k8s-tp-default-dispatchdqs--126ca7f10f7eb9fb
    ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s-um-default-dispatchdqs--126ca7f10f7eb9fb
  creationTimestamp: "2020-04-24T06:48:39Z"
  generation: 1
  name: dispatchdqs
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "492988"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/dispatchdqs
  uid: a1641ba9-85f7-11ea-9f9f-42010a960046
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: janusgraph-service
    servicePort: 8182
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.201.92.97
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Which `Ingress` you want to use? `GKE Ingress` or `Nginx Ingress`? If you want to use GKE ingress, the Service must be `type: NodePort`. If you want to use Nginx Ingress you need to specify annodation like `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` Did you create Ingress from YAML or you deployed it using for example helm? Ive mentioned about GKE and Nginx Ingress in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59875640/11148139

Comment: Thanks @PjoterS I want to use GKE Ingress. I created the Ingress from YAML generated by the online console. The Service was created from helm.

Comment: could you provide tutorial/chart which was used to deploy? I'd like to reproduce it on my env. Also could you provide some logs for troubleshoot?