# 404 not found for GKE Ingress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying with `Ingress` feature in `GKE` Cluster` . Following are the steps I followed

```
  1. Create deployment with below command

     kubectl create deployment hello --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0

  2. Exposed the deployment of type NodePort

     kubectl expose deployment hello --port=8080 --type=NodePort

  3. my ingress manifests is as follows

 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: basic-ingress
   annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce 
 spec:
   rules:      
   - http:
       paths:
       - path: /
       backend:
         serviceName: hello
         servicePort: 8080              

$ kubectl get services
  NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)            AGE
  hello       NodePort        10.0.41.132     <None>      8080:30820/TCP       113m

$ kubectl get ingress
  NAME            HOSTS      ADDRESS        PORTS    AGE
  basic-ingress    *       35.X.X.X        80      26m
```

But when I access the external IP using curl , it throws 404 not found .

Below error can be seen from GKE Console

[image]
I think I am missing something in the `ingress` definition . Please guide to fix this.

Image definition has been taken from this guide
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer

Comment: Would you please use - path: /* instead of - path: / and give an try

Comment: Tried..but still the same

Comment: please try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/62395159/11866104

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. It helped me to validate for GCE based annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to create the same ingress from the scratch (none cluster, none ingress service, none service), and I was able to create it and perform a curl successfully, these were the steps:

1.- Create a cluster (It does not matter the details, just create it as you want)

2.- Connect to the cluster and install kubectl-> sudo apt-get install kubectl

3.- kubectl create deployment hello --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0

4.- kubectl expose deployment hello --port=8080 --type=NodePort

5.- Create the ingress as follows (Without annotations), as per [Creating an Ingress resource](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#creating_an_ingress_resource)

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: basic-ingress
spec:
backend:
serviceName: web
servicePort: 8080

6.- Review your ingress kubectl get ingress basic-ingress

@cloudshell:$ kubectl get ingress basic-ingress
NAME            HOSTS   ADDRESS          PORTS   AGE
basic-ingress   *       130.211.xx.xxx   80      5m46s

7.- And now is working when I have performed the curl:

@cloudshell:$ curl http://130.211.xx.xxx
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: hello-86dbf5b7c6-f7qgl

You were using [ingress annotations](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress#ingress_annotations), and it is another way to create ingress services, but a little bit more advanced. My suggestion is to create it as simple as possible first.

Please try it at this way and let me know about it.

Comment: Thanks . It works   $ curl http://34.120.X.X/
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: hello-86dbf5b7c6-9m4bn

Comment: Trying the same with GCE Ingress

Comment: Why the same does not work  on a SharedVPC based GKE Cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

The same `YAML` definitions are failing for me in a `SharedVPC` . This got resolved after adding the below firewall rule

```
  gcloud compute firewall-rules create k8s-fw-l7--60cada75751e6d79 --network <SharedVPC> --description "GCE L7 firewall rule" --allow tcp:30000-32767 --source-ranges 130.211.0.0/22,209.85.152.0/22,209.85.204.0/22,35.191.0.0/16 --target-tags gke-privatetestgkecluster-cf899a18-node --project <Project>
```

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks